# How to draw a google chart when a tab is showed?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

Google Charts cannot be drawn on a container that is hidden. People suggests few workarounds for this:

- Draw all the charts then hide the divs.
- Draw each chart on demand.
- Use visibility:hidden instead of display:none.

I am using the following code, but it is not working 100%:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $('#Tab2').click(function (e) {
>     drawChart();
> });
> </script>
> ```

I would like to render the chart only when I click in the tab. Is it possible?

Update:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('date', 'Período');
            data.addColumn('number', 'TOTAL');
            data.addColumn('number', 'FECHADOS');
            data.addColumn('number', 'EM ABERTO');

            data.addRows([

                [new Date(2014, 3), 16, 13, 3],
                [new Date(2014, 2), 34, 30, 4],
                [new Date(2014, 1), 33, 30, 3],
                [new Date(2014, 0), 26, 19, 7],
                [new Date(2013, 11), 26, 23, 3],
                [new Date(2013, 10), 43, 40, 3],
                [new Date(2013, 9), 38, 34, 4],
                [new Date(2013, 8), 41, 40, 1],
                [new Date(2013, 7), 42, 40, 2],
                [new Date(2013, 6), 31, 31, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 5), 24, 23, 1],
                [new Date(2013, 4), 29, 29, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 3), 37, 37, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 2), 39, 39, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 1), 29, 29, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 0), 42, 42, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 11), 23, 23, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 10), 26, 26, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 9), 32, 32, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 8), 30, 30, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 7), 31, 31, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 6), 35, 35, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 5), 40, 40, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 4), 44, 44, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 3), 26, 26, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 2), 19, 19, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 1), 27, 27, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 0), 21, 21, 0],
                [new Date(2011, 11), 24, 24, 0],
                [new Date(2011, 10), 19, 19, 0],
                [new Date(2011, 9), 21, 21, 0],
                [new Date(2011, 8), 16, 16, 0]
            ]); 

        var dateFormat = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMM/y'});
            dateFormat.format(data, 0);

        var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
            containerId: 'range_filter_div',
                options: {
                    filterColumnIndex: 0,
                    ui: {
                        chartOptions: {
                            height: 50,
                            fontName: ["Roboto Condensed"],
                            fontSize: ['13'],
                            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                            width: '85%', // must be the same in both the chart and the control
                                chartArea: {
                                    width: '85%' // must be the same in both the chart and the control
                                },
                            hAxis: {
                                format: 'MMM/y'
                                }
                            },
                        chartView: {
                            columns: [0, 1]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        state: {
                            range: {
                            start: new Date(2013, 3),
                            end: new Date(2014, 3)
                                }
                            }
                        });
        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'AreaChart',
            containerId: 'chart_div',
                options: {
                    chartArea: {
                        width: '85%',
                        height: '50%'
                        },
                width: '85%', // must be the same in both the chart and the control
                height: 300,
                fontName: ["Roboto Condensed"],
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                colors: ['#5cb85c','#e0fde0', '#d9534f'],
                curveType: ['none'],
                fontSize: ['13'],
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Período', 
                titleTextStyle: {
                    italic: false,
                    color: 'black',
                    fontSize: 15
                    },
                format: 'MMM/y'
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                    textStyle: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontSize: 12
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 2,
                pointSize: 5,
            tooltip: {
                textStyle: {
                    color: 'Black'
                    },
                showColorCode: false,
                }
            }
        });

        var dash= new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
        dash.bind([rangeFilter], [chart]);
        dash.draw(data);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).resize(function(){
                drawChart();
            });
        });
    }

</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_a);

        function drawChart_a() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('date', 'Período');
            data.addColumn('number', 'ABERTOS');
            data.addColumn('number', 'FECHADOS');
            data.addColumn('number', 'BACKLOG');

            data.addRows([

                [new Date(2014, 3), 16, 13, 3],
                [new Date(2014, 2), 34, 30, 4],
                [new Date(2014, 1), 33, 30, 3],
                [new Date(2014, 0), 26, 19, 7],
                [new Date(2013, 11), 26, 23, 3],
                [new Date(2013, 10), 43, 40, 3],
                [new Date(2013, 9), 38, 34, 4],
                [new Date(2013, 8), 41, 40, 1],
                [new Date(2013, 7), 42, 40, 2],
                [new Date(2013, 6), 31, 31, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 5), 24, 23, 1],
                [new Date(2013, 4), 29, 29, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 3), 37, 37, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 2), 39, 39, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 1), 29, 29, 0],
                [new Date(2013, 0), 42, 42, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 11), 23, 23, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 10), 26, 26, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 9), 32, 32, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 8), 30, 30, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 7), 31, 31, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 6), 35, 35, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 5), 40, 40, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 4), 44, 44, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 3), 26, 26, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 2), 19, 19, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 1), 27, 27, 0],
                [new Date(2012, 0), 21, 21, 0],
                [new Date(2011, 11), 24, 24, 0],
                [new Date(2011, 10), 19, 19, 0],
                [new Date(2011, 9), 21, 21, 0],
                [new Date(2011, 8), 16, 16, 0]
            ]); 

        var dateFormat = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMM/y'});
            dateFormat.format(data, 0);

        var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
            containerId: 'range_filter_div_a',
                options: {
                    filterColumnIndex: 0,
                    ui: {
                        chartOptions: {
                            height: 50,
                            fontName: ["Roboto Condensed"],
                            fontSize: ['13'],
                            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                            width: '85%', // must be the same in both the chart and the control
                                chartArea: {
                                    width: '85%' // must be the same in both the chart and the control
                                },
                            hAxis: {
                                format: 'MMM/y'
                                }
                            },
                        chartView: {
                            columns: [0, 1]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        state: {
                            range: {
                            start: new Date(2013, 3),
                            end: new Date(2014, 3)
                                }
                            }
                        });
        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'AreaChart',
            containerId: 'chart_div_a',
                options: {
                    chartArea: {
                        width: '85%',
                        height: '50%'
                        },
                width: '85%', // must be the same in both the chart and the control
                height: 300,
                fontName: ["Roboto Condensed"],
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                colors: ['#5cb85c','#e0fde0', '#d9534f'],
                curveType: ['none'],
                fontSize: ['13'],
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Período', 
                titleTextStyle: {
                    italic: false,
                    color: 'black',
                    fontSize: 15
                    },
                format: 'MMM/y'
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                    textStyle: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontSize: 12
                    }
                },
                lineWidth: 2,
                pointSize: 5,
            tooltip: {
                textStyle: {
                    color: 'Black'
                    },
                showColorCode: false,
                }
            }
        });

        var dash= new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_a'));
        dash.bind([rangeFilter], [chart]);
        dash.draw(data);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).resize(function(){
                drawChart_a();
            });
        });
    }

</script>

<div class="tabbable top-margin-medium" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a class="text-muted" href="#Group" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="text-muted" href="#New" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Group" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px;">
            <div id="dashboard">
                <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                <div id="range_filter_div" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 20px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="New" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px;">
            <div id="dashboard_a">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#New').click(function (e) {
                    drawChart_a();
                });
                </script>
                <div id="chart_div_a" style="width: 100%;"></div>
                <div id="range_filter_div_a" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 20px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working 100%"?  Does something happen that shouldn't happen?  Does something not happen that should happen?  Is it throwing an error?

Comment: I am using a chart with a ChartRangeFilter. When I use the interact with the ChartRangeFilter the chart renders ok. but the ChartRangeFilter is stucked at the right corner not allowing me to go throught the range.

Comment: Update your question with example code that demonstrates the problem so I can replicate and test it.

Comment: Just updated it. Thanks for your time. I am about to have more than 10 tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your event handlers inside your draw functions, and redraw your dashboards rather than call the draw functions again:

```
function drawChart () {
    // ... chart code

    function redraw () {
        dash.draw(data);
    }

    $(window).resize(redraw);
    $('#Group_link').click(redraw);
}
function drawChart_a () {
    // ... chart code

    function redraw () {
        dash.draw(data);
    }

    $(window).resize(redraw);
    $('#New_link').click(redraw);
}
```

You need to assign the id's "Group_link" and "New_link" (or whatever you decide to call them) to your tab links so they trigger properly:

```
<li class="active">
    <a class="text-muted" id="Group_link" href="#Group" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <a class="text-muted" id="New_link" href="#New" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a>
</li>
```

Comment: It worked but when I open the page, all the charts open in the first tab. After, when I navigate the chart go to the each corret tab.

Comment: That sounds like you have a problem with your tabs, not with the charts.

Comment: Andrew, I just made some more tests and find that with the line `$('#XXX').click(redraw);` I can't select the table chart to copy and paste the data, because the chart is redrawing everytime. I will start a fiddle with the current situation, because the chart only get the right size after my first interaction with it. Thanks

Comment: Those click event handlers should only be on the tab controls, not on the tabs themselves.