# Drawing Google Chart in hidden elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization, hidden

Trying do render Google charts in hidden elements without lucky. The fiddle bellow has an example with bootstrap tabs:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/axr7h/)

Got some help from Andrew here: [How to draw a google chart when a tab is showed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020492/how-to-draw-a-google-chart-when-a-tab-is-showed) but the chart now is re-rendering anytime I interact with it, (for example with the range filter).

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">Tab A</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
               <a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">Tab B</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">Tab C</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="A">
                <div id='ChartA'></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="B">
                <div id='ChartB'></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="C">
                <div id='ChartC'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All the JS code is in the fiddle.

Comment: Hmm...you need to hook into Bootstrap's tab events somehow.  I'll look into them to see if I can figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple example, all I'm doing here is reloading the graphs when the tabs show event gets fired for each tab. I'm sure there's a more elegant solution but it does the job.

```
$("a[href='#A']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['timeline'],
        callback: drawChartA
    });
});

$("a[href='#B']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['timeline'],
        callback: drawChartB
    });
});

$("a[href='#C']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['timeline'],
        callback: drawChartC
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks! It works. I found it weird if I keep clicking in the tabs, the navigation become slow ans slower. But it really did the job. Thanks again.

Comment: It might be a memory leak. I would read the documentation further and see if there's a better method for the job than simply calling `google.load` all the time. You might have to add an additional event callback for when the tab is closed and remove all the old graph references.

Comment: Have a look at [this ticket](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1021), the response towards the bottom suggests calling the `clearChart()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Simple as that:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
});
```

Comment: in your js file

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I looked for.  
Important note: the jquery binding should be defined **after** tab's html code. My way:
`$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')))`